# Button click function doesn't work into an HTML variable | How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Button click function doesn't work into an `HTML` variable, am I wrong or my code is missing something? I'm a beginner in `javasctipt` and this is the first time I use this method and don't know exactly how to fix this issue. So please, How to fix that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my `Jquery` code below:

```js
$(function(){
  var content1 = '<p>This is a paragraph</p><button class="btn">Show other content</button>';

  var content2 = '<h1>This is a title</h1>';

  $(".button").click(function(){
    $(".modal").show();
    $(".modal-content").html(content1);
  });

  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".modal-content").html(content2);
    console.log(content2);
  });
});
```

```css
.modal{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you’re referring to when you use the term “HTML variable”?

Comment: I mean to append HTML tags into body from Javascript variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second click you need to delegate the event from the body. Since the element is not present in the DOM when you are attaching the event. So change this `$(".btn").click(function(){`  to  `$("body").on('click', '.btn', function() {`

```js
$(function() {
  var content1 = '<p>This is a paragraph</p><button class="btn">Show other content</button>';

  var content2 = '<h1>This is a title</h1>';

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".modal").show();
    $(".modal-content").html(content1);
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $(".modal-content").html(content2);
    console.log(content2);
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 300px;
  hieght: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">Open modal</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! you fixed my problem. thank you so much. Sir. and your answer has been accepted. Have a nice day bro:)